# French visa aplication in London

Tags: visas, france

I am a Indian passport holder resident in Botswana, I have UK visa, I am travelling and would like to visit France. Can I apply for French visa in UK ? Also can I also travel to Germany and such other coutries on French visa?

Answer (score 5):

First, it is not a French visa but a visa of the Schengen Area. This is the visa policy thereof and I suggest you read it [Visa policy of the Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area).

Secondly, you can't apply for a Schengen visa in the UK unless you are a resident of the UK.

Basically, you require a Schengen visa and this must be done from Botswana (https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/infosheet_schengen_visas_botswana.pdf) or South Africa depending on the destination. I'm a visa required national myself (South African) but I reside in Ireland on a valid work permit and so therefore I can apply in Ireland for a Schengen visa.

Comment: This is the right answer. I was able to apply for a French visa in London, but I was immediately asked for my British residence permit. You must produce a UK residence permit when applying for a French visa in London, and it must have at least 15 days of validity left.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique for a Schengen short-stay visa the validity requirement is rather greater.